# Stripe custom amount problems

Tags: php

I have some troubles with Stripe custom amount creating. 
I've already managed to create an input for that and used some javascript.

But the problem is - while paying, my server send just a stantard "50$" amount instead of my client's amount.

I guess that the problem is in my "charge.php"
but i have no idea how to connect the inputted amount and my server side code.

( I'm a total noob in javascript and PHP )

So my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com  -->
<!--  Last Published: Sun Nov 12 2017 20:47:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)  -->
<html>
<head>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"
  integrity="sha256-goy7ystDD5xbXSf+kwL4eV6zOPJCEBD1FBiCElIm+U8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
    
<form id="myForm" action="charge.php" method="POST">
  <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" />
  <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
  <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
</form>

<input type="button" id="customButton" value="Pay">

<script>

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_m2pOUJWJ9nOVOZvooj0JmKfk',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#myForm").submit();
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var amount = $("#amount").val() * 100;
  var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amount").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    description: 'Custom amount ($' + displayAmount + ')',
    amount: amount
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>


  <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
</body>
</html>
```

>

And my "charge.php"

```html
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Please tell me what to do with "charge.php" or something

Answer (score 0):

Change your amount value in the charge array to that shown below:

```
$charge=\Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
    'customer' => $customer->id, 
    'amount' => ($_POST['amount']*100),
    'currency' => 'usd' 
    ));
```